# The use of "each" and "either" in context

Tags: grammar

Tell me please which one of the following sentences is correct. If both are correct, then what is the difference.

> Kate asked me if I could lend her one of my cars, and I said, that she could take **each**.
>
> Kate asked me if I could lend her one of my cars, and I said, that she could take **either**.

By the way, should be *each*/*either* or *each one*/*either one*?

Answer (score 1):

> Kate asked me if I could lend her one of my cars, and I said, that she could take each.

Each would only work if Kate took them in sequence. Kate is asking to borrow **one** of the cars, so it wouldn't really work in this situation (there are others where it might though)

> Kate asked me if I could lend her one of my cars, and I said, that she could take either.

This only works if there are **two** cars. For **three or more** consider:

> Kate asked me if I could lend her one of my cars, and I said, that she could take any [of them] [she liked].

(Props to Weathervane for *any*)